# How To Store Cookie For A specification Url

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to store `sessioncookie` for a specific URL 
here is my PHP code for storing the cookie.

I have two URLs at there :-

1. http://example.com/home/login?login=$username&password=$password
2. http://example.com/userhome

I want to store 2nd  URL session cookie but in my PHP I am getting only first URL cookie so please suggest me what I do ?

```
<?php
if(!is_dir("Cookies"))
{
    mkdir("Cookies");
}

ob_implicit_flush(1);
flush();
ob_flush();
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(0);

$username= $_POST['uid'];      
$password= $_POST['pwd'];

$sleep= $_POST['sleep'];      
$bids= $_POST['st'];
$bide= $_POST['en'];
$new= $_POST['nw'];



$url = "http://example.com/home/";
$cookiefile = rand(1, 9999).'.txt';
$cookies = str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__).'/Cookies/'.$cookiefile);
$ch = curl_init();
login:
//echo"$username";
//echo"$password";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/home/login?login=$username&password=$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept: */*"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryU7y9pmePNyEDuAUD");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"User-Agent: Mozilla/7.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0" );
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=$username&userpassword=$password&login=submit");
$html = curl_exec( $ch );





flush();
ob_flush();
for ($x = $y; $x <= $z; $x+=0.01)

{

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/userhome");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept: */*"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryU7y9pmePNyEDuAUD");
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"User-Agent: Mozilla/7.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0" );

$html = curl_exec( $ch );
?>
```

Comment: session cookies are stored per domain not per url's

Comment: What you wanna do exactly?

Comment: so now please tell me how to save sessioncookie for 2nd url

Comment: what do you want to accomplish 'login via curl' is it not working?

Comment: ya everything is fine in curl codes actually i am tring to bypassing caaptcha with session cookies session cookies contain the captcha alphabate so with the use  of session cookies i am tring to bypassing it

Comment: what do you want to exactly say 'session cookies contain the captcha alphabate' or  'session array contain the captcha alphabet' . BTW session is same for all url's of the domain.